# Botão não aparece em uma activity e aparece em outra

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

Eu estou com um problema que não sei identificar onde se encontra. Eu tenho um layout que roda um vídeo, com um botão na frente, só que o botão não aparece apesar de que quando eu clico na área do botão ele funciona normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O botão deveria aparecer na área em vermelho.

Só que eu tenho outro layout rotacionado idêntico, onde o botão aparece, e os dois possuem o mesmo código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele aparece na área vermelha normalmente, e também funciona.

Esse é o layout onde o botão não aparece

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:rotation="180"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/vb_view"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/vb_lutadores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/lutadores"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

E esse é o código dele

```
package br.com.mscp.multiboxe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Vb extends Activity {

    ImageButton vb_lutadores;

    VideoView vb_view;
    Uri vb_video;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vb_layout);

        vb_lutadores = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.vb_lutadores);
        vb_lutadores.setEnabled(false);

        vb_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vb_view);
        vb_video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vb);
        vb_view.setVideoURI(vb_video);
        vb_view.start();

        vb_lutadores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Vb.this, Menu_lutadores.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vb_lutadores.setEnabled(true);
                vb_lutadores.bringToFront();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 800);
    } 
}
```

Esse é o layout onde o botão aparece

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/vc_view"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/vc_lutadores"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/lutadores"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

E esse é o código

```
package br.com.mscp.multiboxe;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Vc extends Activity {

    ImageButton vc_lutadores;

    VideoView vc_view;
    Uri vc_video;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vc_layout);

        vc_lutadores = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.vc_lutadores);
        vc_lutadores.setVisibility(vc_lutadores.INVISIBLE);
        vc_lutadores.setEnabled(false);

        vc_view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vc_view);
        vc_video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vc);
        vc_view.setVideoURI(vc_video);
        vc_view.start();

        vc_lutadores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Vc.this, Menu_lutadores.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                vc_lutadores.setVisibility(vc_lutadores.VISIBLE);
                vc_lutadores.setEnabled(true);
                vc_lutadores.bringToFront();
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 800);
    } ´
}
```

Alguém sabe onde está o erro porque eu não consigo encontrar, se puder ajudar eu agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi corretamente, o resultado desejado seria o botão aparecer em cima (*on top*) do VideoView.

Tente englobar tanto o VideoView quanto o botão dentro do `FrameLayout`

> O FrameLayout foi projetado para bloquear uma área na tela para exibir um único item. [...] Você pode, no entanto, *adicionar vários filhos* a um FrameLayout. [...] Views filhas são desenhadas em uma pilha, **com a filha adicionada mais recentemente no topo**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="180"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/vb_view"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/vb_lutadores"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/lutadores"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note que o `RelativeLayout` do terceiro nível foi removido e as propriedades em relação a ele no `ImageButton` e `VideoView` foram substituídas por `android:layout_gravity` como especificado [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: Quando testo com essas modificações o videoview não fica mais em tela cheia, fica com uma barra branca em cima. E se eu tento acrescentar o RelativeLayout com o AlingParent no videoview o botão desaparece novamente

Comment: Depois de muitos testes, a única solução que encontrei foi retirar as rotações e usar a imagem já rotacionada, porque sem elas o botão aparece, só não consigo entender o porquê